# Windows Phone XAML - Access specific parents child from contextmenu in code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is my xaml:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}" BorderThickness="0" Width="Auto" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Name="tiltPanel4" Margin="0,0,0,20" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Padding="0,0,0,0"  Click="EMail_Click" >
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="E_Mail" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="email" FontSize="36" Margin="0" Padding="0" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="EMailBlock" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="22" Padding="0" Margin="0" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        <toolkit:ContextMenu Name="ContextMenu4" IsZoomEnabled="False" >
            <toolkit:MenuItem Name="copy3" Header="copy" Click="Copy_Click"/>
        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

I want to copy the text from the `EmailBlock` to the Clipboard, when Copy_Click is triggered. Copy_Click is used in different contextmenu with the same structure, therefor I cant just read the text from the EmailBlock.
How can I access it?

Comment: use MVVM pattern and bind the TextBlock.Text to some property in the DataContext. Similary instead on click event, use ICommand in ViewModel to capture MenuItem click. In the Command handler you can copy the property text to which your textblock is bound to the clipboard

Comment: I found a dirty solution which works for me. Still thanks for your help. Im not really into MVVM and dont have the motiviation to implement it in this app.